# The P tag of the CK editor returns the older value instead of updated one

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, ckeditor

```
I am unable to edit my note using CKeditor in first attempt it works in second and so on attempts (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV0kO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV0kO.png)

The output you can see in the first attempt if i save this, it will be same as Test instead of Testing (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7qzI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7qzI.png)


The output you can see here it is in the second attempt after save the first one note text.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeAIh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeAIh.png)

/* Controller code */
```

public async Task EditNote(string id, string description)
{
try
{
string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
var orgId = await _userService.GetOrganizationByNoteId(id);
if (user.UserType == (int)EnumTypeOfUser.Organization)
{
NoteReq obj=new NoteReq();
obj.LastModifiedBy = orgId.CreatedBy;
obj.OrganizationId = orgId.OrganizationId;
obj.Id = id;
obj.Description = description;

```
                var result = await _noteService.UpdateNote(obj);

                if (result!=null)
                {

                    return Json(new { status = HttpStatusCode.OK});

                }
            }
            return Json(new { status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message = "Not Able to process" });
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
/* Controller code */
```

```
<div>
 <div class="card-body areacls cardBox" contenteditable="true" id="@areaId" data-href="@item.Id" onclick="createEditor(@areaId)">
       @Html.Raw(item.Description)
 </div>
<div class="btn-footer" style="display:none;">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default text-right" onclick="loadListView()">Cancel</button>
                              <button type="button" onclick="saveDes('@hoverId')" class="btn btn-primary text-right" data-id="@item.Id">Save</button>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
var editors = new Map();
 function createEditor(elementToReplace) {

            return ClassicEditor
                .create(elementToReplace)
                .then(editor => {
                    editors.set(elementToReplace, editor);

                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
        }

function saveDes(hoverId) {
        debugger;
        $("#" + hoverId).removeClass('col-md-8');
        $("#" + hoverId).find('#dot').css('display', 'block');
        $("#" + hoverId).find('.btn-footer').css('display', 'none');
        var dataId = $("#" + hoverId).attr("data-id");
        var data = $("#" + hoverId).find("p").html();
        if (data != "" && data != undefined) {
            updateNote(dataId, data);
        }
        loadListView();
    }


function updateNote(dataId, description) {
        debugger;
        var id = dataId;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Note/EditNote',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: { Id: id, Description: description },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.status == 400) {
                    toastr.error(response.message);
                }
                else if (response.status == 200) {
                    loadListView();
                }
            }
        });
    }

function loadListView() {
        $('#pills-recent').load('/Note/_NotesList');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Please check once  more

Comment: Hi,@Ruman Ali,could you show all html codes related when you debug  instead of razor codes?